# Powershell - automatize connecting to MS-Graph

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-intune

Is there a way to automatize connecting to *MSGraph*?

I have found a way to automatize connecting to *AzureAD* by using next two lines of code, which works perfectly without any pop-up.

```
$UPN = whoami /upn
Connect-AzureAD -AccountId $UPN
```

Is there something similar for *Connect-MSGraph*?

All my google searches on this topic have resulted in automatizing connecting to *MgGraph* which is not what I need.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can automate the connection to MS Graph with Powershell, we gonna need Microsoft.Graph.Authentication which give the Connect-MgGraph needed for connecting to MS Graph.

Dont forget to replace `your_client_id` `your_client_secret` and `your_tenant_id` with your values

```
Install-Module -Name Microsoft.Graph.Authentication

$clientId = "your_client_id"
$clientSecret = "your_client_secret"
$tenantId = "your_tenant_id"
Connect-MgGraph -ClientSecretCredential $(New-Object Microsoft.Graph.Authentication.ClientSecretCredential -ArgumentList $tenantId, $clientId, $clientSecret)
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, for this to work I need to create an app in Azure from which I would get client_id and client_secret?
What's the purpose of creating such an application? I'm not sure if I need it.
Is there a way to do it without creating unnecessary applications?

Comment: This will get you authenticate and access to Microsoft Graph API